# Shipment combinations/Hyper geometric distribution word problem.

Tags: statistics

[image]

My train of thought says:

$P(X=1)=\frac {\binom {4}{1} \binom {19}{2} } {20 \choose 3} = 0.60$
This is solution cropped out from a paper. I believe the person made a mistake or most likely I did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability to take exactly $k$ defective items in the sample consisting of $3$ items is:
$$P(Y=k) = \dfrac{\dbinom 4k \cdot \dbinom {\color{blue}{16}}{3-k}}{\dbinom {20}{3}},$$
since you want to choose the $(3 - k)$ **non-defective** items from the non-defective ones, which are $16$. In our case, where $k = 1$, after doing the calculations, the correct answer is **d)**.